# Measure data transfer rate over tcp using c#

Tags: c#, bandwidth, tcpclient, transfer

I am sending a huge file over TCP using C#, and would like to measure the download speed.
How can I capture the transfer rate every second? If I use `IPv4InterfaceStatistics` or a similar method, I capture the device transfer rate instead of capturing the file transfer rate.
The problem with capturing device transfer rate is that it captures all data passing through the network device instead of the single file that I transfer.

How can I capture the file transfer rate?

Comment: In the method that receives the data, check every second how much data you've got and divide by the time that has passed. Or did I miss some difficulty here?

Comment: well, how can i check every second how much data i successfully received in c#? maybe i miss something. i cannot find any related method in networkstream. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have control over the stream to tell how much is read, you can create timestamps before and after a stream read and then calculate the speed based on the number of received or sent bytes:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;

// some code here...

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begining of the loop

int offset = 0;
stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();

bytes[] buffer = new bytes[1024]; // 1 KB buffer
int actualReadBytes = myStream.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length);

// Now we have read 'actualReadBytes' bytes 
// in 'stopWath.ElapsedMilliseconds' milliseconds.

stopwatch.Stop();
offset += actualReadBytes;
int speed = (actualReadBytes * 8) / stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds; // kbps

// End of the loop
```

You should put the `Stream.Read` in a `try/catch` block and handle exceptions that could occur. It's the same for writing to streams and calculating the speed, only these two lines are affected:

```
myStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
int speed = (buffer.Length * 8) / stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds; // kbps
```

Comment: this is exactly what i did. the problem with this method is that the results always very much lower than actual. for example, when i send data, i watch the device data transfer using tools that use IPv4InterfaceStatistics. with this, i can see the actual transfer rate of the device. when i find the average of the transfer rate, the results always lower that IPv4InterfaceStatistics. my interest is, the maximum data transfer, not average. thanks.

Comment: This is the real valuable data you have sent or received. Other layers will add headers/trailers to your data based on the using protocol. For example if you use `SSL` then the device transferred data is much more than `actualBytes`. Also `OS` data transfer is added to this (for `DNS` queries...). This is the only way you can take control over data transfer. You can estimated the overload for you case and multiply this speed at that ratio to achieve a more near speed but not the exact speed.

Comment: I might be missing something, but if you times it by 8 aren't you calculating the kiloBITS (Kb/sec) and not the kiloBYTES (KB/sec)?

Comment: @Fidel: You right. I meant `kbps` which should be all in small letters according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KBPS