# What is a valid way to track ReadAsStreamAsync download speed rate

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm learning C# 5 async / await on some real-world example - save a file from web with displaying download speed rate.

There is a method that I'm worried is wrong, especially with a download speed calculation.

```
public async Task DownloadAsyncDemo(Uri requestUri, IProgress<string> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var downloadedFileName = "file";
            var downloadDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TmpDownload");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri))
                {
                    using (var responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        if (responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition != null)
                            downloadedFileName = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                        else
                            downloadedFileName = Path.GetFileName(requestUri.LocalPath);

                        downloadedFileName = Path.Combine(downloadDirectory, downloadedFileName);

                        if (!Directory.Exists(downloadDirectory))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadDirectory);

                        int bufferSize = 1024;  // 1 KB buffer
                        using (var httpStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                        {
                            using (var filestream = new FileStream(downloadedFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4084, true))
                            {
                                //await httpStream.CopyToAsync(filestream); // need more low level logic below
                                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    sw.Reset();
                                    sw.Start();
                                    int num = await httpStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                                    sw.Stop();
                                    if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0)
                                        progress.Report(string.Format("Time taken: {0} ms Data size: {1} KB Speed: {2} kbps", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, num, num * 8 / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
                                    int bytesRead;
                                    if ((bytesRead = num) != 0)
                                        await filestream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                                    else
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I run it like:

```
var dManger = DownloadManager.Instance;
var cancelationToken = new CancellationToken();
Task.Run(() => dManger.DownloadAsyncDemo(new Uri("http://speedtest.tokyo.linode.com/100MB-tokyo.bin")
                , new Progress<string>(data => Console.WriteLine(data)), cancelationToken));
```

I get result like:

[image]

I'm worried that something is wrong with my code because for download speed rate calculation I get speed from 81 to 8192 kpbs.
In my async task example I used download rate counting approach taken from [Measure data transfer rate over tcp using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641733/measure-data-transfer-rate-over-tcp-using-c-sharp)

What am I doing wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but rather *expectation* you have on displaying the data.

Change from instant value over single interval to average over long period of time (whole download/last 1-3-10 seconds) to get representation you expect.

Comment: Thanks! Alexei, can you please suggest a good way of doing it every second for example? I guess Timer or Task.Deley is needed here, but I'm not sure how to make it work right in async Task to get the average download rate.

Comment: I'd blindly add values {time, block size} to array and do just do something like `.SkipWhile(item => item.timeFromStartMs < currentTimeFromStartMs - 1000).Sum(item => item.BlockSize)`. (You'll  need something better than linear search in full history if you have really large download)